# Problem installing snort barnyard2

Tags: 12.04, snort

Hi I have problem installing barnyard2 in snort. I am trying to do this steps using the Snort PDF guide barnyard2 section.

```
sudo tar zxvf barnyard2-1.9.tar.gz
cd barnyard2-1.9
sudo ./configure --with-mysql
```

At first when I try to do this I encounter an error saying:

```
ERROR: unable to find mysql headers (mysql.h)
```

`
So I went to install libmysql-dev following the instructions from this site [here](http://spuder.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/unable-to-find-mysql-headers-file-mysql-h/). Problem regarding mysql.h was gone but I got another error when I tried this

```
sudo ./configue --with-mysql command.
```

This time error is

```
ERROR: unable to find mysqlclient library (libmysqlclient.*).
```

So I went to follow instructions on this site [here](http://techinterplay.com/how-to-fix-the-error-unable-to-find-mysqlclient-library-libmysqlclient.html) and tried to locate libmysqlclient where I have the following output:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.shlibs
```

I tried the command sudo ./configure –with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ and 
sudo ./configure –with-mysql-libraries=/usr/share/doc/

After each command I was asked again for the first error message I encountered

```
ERROR: unable to find mysql headers (mysql.h)
```

It seems like whenever I tried to set the path to where mysql.h  or libmysqlclient is located the error just pops up. How do I solve this one? Just to let you know am just an average user of ubuntu and i don't know alot of commands. I really appreciate if anyone could help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need this answer anymore, but here's how I got it to work:

```
./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --with-mysql-includes=/usr/include/
```

In your case just use: i386-linux-gnu instead of the x86_64 folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this using CentOS 7 with Percona MySql.

I solved my issue by running:

yum install Percona-Server-devel

Comment: Your command will not work for Ubuntu , [here](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/apt_repo.html#installing-percona-server-from-percona-apt-repository) is the alternative to your solution for Ubuntu.